# How to anchor right corner of the last column to TableView?

Tags: qml, tableview

I'm using TableView and I have this issue. [Example of what I achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmdON.png).
So basically I have N column and when I narrow a last one I get N+1 with a new empty column. How can i freeze a right border of last column? I need to resize them, so `TableViewColumn.resizable::false` not gonna solve the problem.

Comment: Could it be the same issue that is mentioned at the bottom of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25945229/how-to-change-the-color-background-text-of-header-of-tableview-in-qt5/25946022#25946022) answer?

Comment: @Mitch, sorry, but I don't get how this is connected with my issue.

Comment: Then I'm not really sure what the problem is. :p I thought that the problem was the white bit at the end of the column?

Comment: Nope @Mitch, he just have a sort of "ghost" column, a last empty column. Have a look to the linked picture.

Comment: Ah, thanks. :) But what does "narrow a last one" mean? Make it smaller by resizing? I'm not at a PC, so I can't try that out..

Comment: Ah! Don't assume I've understood anything else than the picture. :)

Comment: Yes, when i resize any of columns, I get a fake column as well.